# cmake build a shared library that contains all its dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake

I have built a shared library that depends on a bunch of other libraries. But when loading that shared library, it needs the dependent libraries to be present in order to run properly. I want this shared library to be portable and hence want it to contain all the dependencies in itself. Is there a way in cmake to do this or what is the best solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not related with CMake, but with concepts of linking. You should link with static version of all your dependent libraries.

Comment: But does find_package() always give you the shared version?

Comment: @user3513507 It depends on how the author of FindXXX.cmake wrote it, and this is a hell.